# Check if condition is True with .loc and if is set 1

Tags: python, pandas

```
varv = -1

df:
                       Open        VarC  Position
Date                                                                 
2019-11-25 10:00:00    30.38   -0.325098       0.0
2019-11-25 16:00:00    30.59   -1.538955       0.0
2019-11-26 10:00:00    30.56   -2.244309       0.0
2019-11-26 16:00:00    30.53   -3.584000       0.0
2019-11-27 10:00:00    30.20   -0.640000       0.0

df.loc[df['VarC']  <= varv, 'Position'] = 1
```

Its doesnt working. df['Position'] still 0.0.
Suggestions how it may set 1 to 'Position'?
Already try using if and still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Position'] = df['Position'].where(df['VarC'] > varv, 1)
```

Output:

```
print(df)
                      Open      VarC  Position
Date                                          
2019-11-25 10:00:00  30.38 -0.325098       0.0
2019-11-25 16:00:00  30.59 -1.538955       1.0
2019-11-26 10:00:00  30.56 -2.244309       1.0
2019-11-26 16:00:00  30.53 -3.584000       1.0
2019-11-27 10:00:00  30.20 -0.640000       0.0
```

Comment: doesnt work too. its setting all values to 1. Neither if its condition (df['VarC'] < varv

Comment: i tryed 
if df1016c['Position'].where(df1016c['VarV'] <= varv, 1).any() == True:
    df1016c['Position'] = 1
elif df1016c['Position'].where(df1016c['VarC'] >= varv, -1).any() == True:
    df1016c['Position'] = -1
else:
    df1016c['Position'] = 0 < doesnt work

then i tryed:
df1016c['Position'] = np.where(df1016c['VarV'] <= varv, 1,0)

Both doesnt work. they are all setting 1 to all rows!

Comment: no, its just setting the `Position` values to 1 where `VarC` values are smaller then -1. I added the output for your input

Comment: Thank you luigigi! its working!